# Keep release branch up to date with master except a couple files

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

I have a master branch and a release branch. When I'm ready for a new numbered release version, I want to get it up-to-date with the master branch but maintain different versions of composer.json and auth.php in each branch.

My composer.json requires some `dev-master` versions in the dev branch but should only require versioned releases in the release branch. auth.php contains different database credentials for the server-side/release version compared with the local development version.

I'm new to git other than basic commits.

Here's what I did for my very first release version

```
git clone ...
cd ...
git checkout -b release 
nano composer.json //and change dev-master requires to 0.1.* requires
nano auth.php //and change db credentials
git add -A
git commit -m "composer and auth changes for release"
git push origin release
git tag -a 0.1.0
git push origin 0.1.0
```

Then I'm able to composer require `0.1.*` and it works!

What I want to do for the next version release is:

```
git clone ...
cd ...
git checkout --track origin/release //to switch to the release branch
git merge ... //get changes from master, but DO NOT overwrite the release-version's composer.json or auth.php
git push origin release
git tag -a 0.1.1
git push origin 0.1.1
```

Then I would ssh into my server and `composer update` to get to the latest version of my site (which is in a private repository).

How do I do the git merge line in the second block of git code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, one detail I think needs to be corrected in the question: after the merge, you probably do in fact want to change `composer.json` to have the new version number, say `0.1.1`.

Now, to answer your question, I expect `git merge master` will do what you want when you are about to create 0.1.1. Since `composer.json` and `auth.php` were changed on the `release` branch after the last merge-base, `git merge` should recognize that it should keep those changes when it merges in changes from `master`. If you also changed those files on master, then you'd expect a conflict, which would give you a chance to fix the merge before completing it.

If things don't work as I describe, can you indicate what happens exactly?

Whether `git merge` does the right thing or not, the next step would be to edit `composer.json` to say version `0.1.1` and commit that on the `release` branch. Edit and commit `auth.php` if needed - but it should not be needed. Then continue with the rest of your workflow (push, tag, push).

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure if `git merge` would work that way or not. It sounds like it works exactly how I was hoping. And you're definitely right about changing the package version in composer before pushing the new release. I just had my first run at branching & tagging through the command line two days ago & just wanted to make sure for the next version I do, which may or may not be in the near future.